# What does '@' mean in an SQLi query?

Tags: php, sql

I am new to PHP/Mysql, I've seen the @ sign used in SQL queries and wasn't able to find what it meant. Could anyone explain it, please? Thank you in advance.

```
set @i = 0;
select *, @i := @i + 1
from post_table
where @i < 10 or date = today
order by date desc;
```

Comment: Please provide an example of it being used.

Comment: [User-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski. Sweet! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `sql` context it means a variable

EXAMPLE

```
SET @var = 1;
SELECT @var
```

In the `php` context it means to suppress errors

EXAMPLE

```
@foo(); //This code will not output errors
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. One other question I have then related to your response is how do you define the '@var' in PHP? When I try typing it like so '@var = 1;' as a line by itself I get a syntax error.

Comment: @user3141817 MySQL variables should be specified within the query statement. To PHP, the `@i` will be just characters in the string.